# Can I #include multiple header files?

Tags: c++

For example `#include "example.h, example2.h, example3.h"` instead of `#include` 3 times on 3 lines.

Is this possible?

It came up on a test and I was wondering.

Comment: The C++ standard would be the proper resource to check; it describes all such syntax very precisely.  Did you check it, and if so, what part are you looking for help in understanding?  Likewise, did you try it in a compiler?

Comment: Nope that's not how the standard preprocessor is defined to work. Any why would you want to anyway? Cramming together code like that only makes it harder to read, harder to understand, and harder to maintain.

Comment: If you make a header file called `example.h, example2.h, example3.h` and in that header file you do `#include "example.h"`, `#include "example2.h"`, and `#include "example3.h"` it will work.  But it would be very clumsy, and doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 3):

No the `include` preprocessing directive, only takes a single file, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include

The question is, would it really benefit you to merge includes to a single line. I would guess having includes on separate lines, makes managing them easier.

So basically you can include any number of files, but only one per `include` directive.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I #include multiple header files?

Yes. You can do that using multiple include directives.

> For example, #include "example.h, example2.h, example3.h" Instead of #include 3 times on 3 lines

Not in practice. Technically, the C++ language doesn't really specify how the path maps to a "file" does it specify what a "file" is, so you could have a theoretical language implementation where you could do something like that. But such language implementation doesn't exist to my knowledge, nor would using such trick be portable to actually existing systems.

You'll need multiple include directives to include multiple files.